# Ошибка "Failed to compare two elements in the array"

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

Есть коллекция и её свойство

```cs
private ObservableCollection<Test> myCollection = new();
public ObservableCollection<Test> MyCollection
        {
            get => myCollection;
            set
            {
                myCollection = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

Я при помощи LINQ создаю запрос и записываю результат в мою коллекцию

```cs
IEnumerable<Test> testQuery =
            from test in myCollectionBackup
            where test.NameTest.ToUpper().StartsWith(TestFind.Text.ToUpper()) //TestFind.Text это текст получаемый из объекта формы
            orderby test
            select test;
MyCollection = new(testQuery);
```

При получении данных в первый раз этот кусок кода отрабатывает, но при других попытках он работать перестаёт и выдает ошибку

```cs
System.InvalidOperationException: "Failed to compare two elements in the array."
```

Тип Test

```cs
 public partial class Test
    {
        public Test() { }
        public Test(int id, string nameTest, string subject, DateTime date, string filePath)
        {
            Id = id;
            NameTest = nameTest;
            Subject = subject;
            Date = date;
            FilePath = filePath;
        }
        public Test(string nameTest, string subject, DateTime date, string filePath)
        {
            NameTest = nameTest;
            Subject = subject;
            Date = date;
            FilePath = filePath;
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string NameTest { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
        public string FilePath { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Выбрать элемент какого-то типа из какой-то коллекции неизвестного типа, где поле или свойство `NameTest` начинавется с свойства `Text` какой-то другой неизвестной сущности, а потом отсортировать это по изначальной сущности, взятой из какой-то коллекции. Хороший запрос, только непонятно, с чем он работает.

Comment: @aepot, я дополнил, этого хватит?

Comment: Ну, наверное нужно компаратор у класса описать, а то как `LINQ` будет два объекта класса между собой сравнивать, особенно для сортировки?

Comment: Нужно реализовать `IComparable<T>` для `Test`.

Comment: Так ладно, я сделал по другому и оно работает, всем спасибо